# Screen capture from jsfiddle using phantom js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, jsfiddle

I have to capture a generated chart's screenshot from jsfiddle.net to show someone. I'm using phantomjsfor this purpose. Now here is the code I'm using

```
page.open(modifiedUrl.url, function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                  //http://fiddle.jshell.net/fusioncharts/B2t38/show/light/
                  console.log("created " + modifiedUrl.unique_str+".png");
                  page.render(modifiedUrl.unique_str+".png");
                  counter+=1;
                  startRender();    
            }, 30000);

        });
```

The url is given in the comment line. Now what happening is I'm getting a trimmed image always with a scroller. But when i'm hitting the url directly there is no sign of scroller. Is there any way to get the scroller free untrimmed image. I have tried with view port setting functionality which is not working also I tried using clipRect property which is not also working.

Comment: It would probably help if you could provide an image of which shows your problem.

Comment: Somehow I managed to made a solve of the problem I'm using page.viewportSize property to set the height and width as page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 }; now i'm getting a untrimmed image the rest will i perform using photoshop

Comment: That's what I thought, but it would still help for future readers if you would include the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS has a default viewport size of 400x300. For most sites that use fixed widths this is too small which is why a scrollbar appears and this is why when using the Selenium Webdrivers elements cannot be interacted with, because they are hidden out of view.
For other sites the mobile site will be shown (which is probably based on media queries).

To solve this, you should set the viewport to something desktop-like before opening the page:

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 800 };
```

(or higher depending on your requirement)

---

You can check this by running `phantomjs` without any arguments in interactive mode and retrieving the viewportSize.

```
$ phantomjs
phantomjs> var page = require('webpage').create();
undefined
phantomjs> page.viewportSize
{
   "height": 300,
   "width": 400
}
```

Comment: In your case the chart is not responsive and is therefore fixed in size which is bigger than the viewportSize.

Comment: yeah thats also true @artjom